# What form of ECC can we use to make sure our newly invented ECC based crypto-systems are quantum secure?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography

It seems a lot of crypto-systems that are based on elliptic curves are susceptible to quantum computing attacks.

Hence, what forms of ECC cryptosystems are quantum secure, and how can we prove that?

Is there any good place to start with ECC (before moving on to different adaptations of ECC)? I have seen some resources but the math behind those papers seems very confusing, I don't even know what kind of math it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditional Elliptic Curve Cryptography (working in the group of points on an elliptic curve over a finite field) is vulnerable to an attack by a quantum computer running Shor's algorithm and is thus not considered a Quantum-Safe.

However there is a true Post Quantum Key Exchange algorithm which uses the mathematics of elliptic curves and is considered secure by experts who have studied it so far. This key exchange is known as [Supersingular isogeny key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange).

Comment: Thank you. I believe I have seen that for a bit, but isogeny seems to be another topic to study also.